# Why does Linq ForEach not provide the same compiler error hints as a normal foreach loop?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, compiler-errors

```
List<(int integer, string str)> myTupleList;
        
foreach (var tuple in myTupleList)
    tuple = (tuple.integer, tuple.str);
    
myTupleList.ForEach(tuple =>
    tuple = (tuple.integer, tuple.str));
```

Why does the foreach give a compiler error, but not the Linq.ForEach?

Irrelevant details to get to 220 characters:

I wasted 2 hours because I forgot that you can't assign to the iteration variable in a foreach. While it was obviously my fault, it would have been nice to get a compiler error to save me some frustration. Why can't Linq.ForEach do this?

Comment: ["Why can't..." questions like this is unclear.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819/5133585) To any answer that says "because X", you can continue asking "Then why is X the case?", and so on. Can you describe what kind of answer you are looking for?

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @Sweeper My question is an attempt to learn why the C# compiler creators cannot or choose not to make this consistent.

Comment: Nitpick: `ForEach` is not a LINQ method. It's a member of the `List<T>` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable you declare in `foreach` is considered a part of the [`foreach` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1395-the-foreach-statement). The language spec calls it the "iteration variable". The syntax also looks distinct from a normal variable declaration, as it is followed by `in`. Because of this, it is more justified to add special restrictions to it, like not being able to reassign it.

`ForEach(x => ...)` on the other hand, is not one single syntactic construct like `foreach` is. It is merely a call to a method called `ForEach`, and passes a lambda expression to that method. Unlike the iteration variable of a `foreach`, the `x` here is nothing special, just the parameter of a lambda expression.

[Lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1219-anonymous-function-expressions) represent "inline" method definitions - its parameters are like method parameters, which have always been reassignable. A language change such as "all lambda parameters are not allowed to be reassigned" would be hard to justify, and a change like "only the parameters of lambdas passed to methods named `ForEach` are not allowed to be reassigned" would not be practical to implement. In general it is difficult to know where a lambda is going to be passed.

That said, the newly introduced [`in` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier) modifier prevents method parameters from being reassigned, but alas, it is too late - changing `ForEach` to take a lambda with an `in` parameter would be a breaking change.

Answer (score 1):

From List.cs (trimmed):

```cs
public void ForEach(Action<T> action)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
    {
        action(_items[i]);
    }
}
```

Since Linq iterates over the list by index, there is no way for the compiler to know that you're modifying an iterator, whereas `foreach` is obvious enough for the compiler to realize what you're trying to do.